# LibGdx TmxMapLoader load external files

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I tried to load an TiledMap from the sdcard.
In TmxMapLoader.java is says...

```
 * Loads the {@link TiledMap} from the given file. The file is resolved via the {@link FileHandleResolver} set in the
 * constructor of this class. By default it will resolve to an internal file.
```

So, how can I change the default value to external?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide custom FileHandleResolver in constructor:

```
TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader(new ExternalFileHandleResolver()).load("level1.tmx");
```

More info about FileHandleResolver: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/loaders/FileHandleResolver.html