# Libgdx TmxMapLoader not working

Tags: libgdx

`TmxMapLoader` is driving me insane! It's working in one file while not working in the other, they are in the same directory/package and it's the same code!!

**ElementTowerDefense.java** (working fine!)

```
package com.etd;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;

public class ElementTowerDefense extends ApplicationAdapter {

private TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;
private TiledMap tiledMap;

@Override
public void create () {
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map/etd_1.tmx");
    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);        
}

}
```

**GameState.java** (not working!!)

```
package com.etd;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
public class GameState {

private TiledMap tiledMap;
private TiledMapRenderer tiledMapRenderer;  

public GameState()
{       
        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map/etd_1.tmx");
        tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);    
}   
}
```

The exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.resolvers.InternalFileHandleResolver.resolve(InternalFileHandleResolver.java:26)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.AssetLoader.resolve(AssetLoader.java:42)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:91)
>     at
>   com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:80)
>     at com.etd.GameState.(GameState.java:24)  at
>   com.etd.ElementTowerDefense.(ElementTowerDefense.java:22)   at
>   com.etd.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:12)

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell where do you call GameState from?
For example, if you call GameState before the app is initialised (meaning Gdx API) the resolvers might not be ready to be used.

Comment: well,it's a comment not exact answer of the question and this is against the rules of SO  .

Comment: Sure, I know, but since I don't have enough reputation for commenting is the only way i have to help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25506738/1079437.

Basically as Yuraj said, you need to use a FileHandleResolver in constructor like this:

```
TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader(new ExternalFileHandleResolver()).load("map/etd_1.tmx");
```